# What means "Take the tensor product with $\mathbb{Q}$ here?

Tags: modules, homology-cohomology, tensor-products

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOwHR.png)

I am bit confused, because normally I would have looked at $\mathbb{Z}^k \otimes \mathbb{Q}$, but that does not make sense with the matrices given here. Am I supposed to replace $\mathbb{Z}^2$ by $ \mathbb{Q} \otimes \mathbb{Q}$ here??

Comment: You need to provide more context for the sentence you want to understand. What is "here"?

Comment: Sorry, i mean by here in the task, that i have forgotten to add. I did it now.

Comment: If you have a map $\Bbb Z^k\to\Bbb Z^l$ given by a matrix $M$, then tensoring with $\Bbb Q$ makes the map called $M\otimes \operatorname{Id}$ given by $n\otimes \frac pq\mapsto Mn\otimes \frac pq$